# Is The Flutter option when adding application in Firebase alternative for adding IOS and Android separately

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cli

when I was trying to add Firebase to my Flutter project, I noticed there is a Flutter option along side with other platform options, (the last option in the photo)
[image]

Also this is what it takes you to when clicking on it

[image]

So, I've been wondering if this method is an alternative for adding Firebase to Flutter App the old way (IOS and Android separately)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, sort of.

The process that the console guides you through, uses the FlutterFire CLI to create those apps rather than you creating them manually in the Firebase console. The end result is indeed that you have an app descriptor for each platform that you target in your Flutter app, which may be more than just iOS and Android these days.

Comment: thank you for your answer, and about the configuration that should be done in the local project itself (placing the google services, signing the app...etc), is it no longer needed with this solution?

Comment: If you generate or connect the apps through the CLI, it generates a `firebase_options.dart` that replaces the need for `google-services.json`.