# What is the difference between selecting `Android`, `iOS` or `Flutter` when adding Firebase to Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-console

What is the difference between selecting `Android`, `iOS` or `Flutter` when adding Firebase to Flutter app?

I understand that Flutter is a hybrid app that is able to run on both Android and iOS and selecting  `Android` and `iOS` is the normal way that I will do when I trying to add my Firebase to my app. However, i realize there is a new `Flutter` option.[image: May refer image attached]

May i know what is the difference between those 2 when trying to add Firebase to my app? thank you

Comment: Here is What you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72914133/14287132

Answer (score 2):

Probably whats most important difference is that (right now) you dont have to register the app if you choose the Flutter option. But if you do it the old way around its still fine, just with this option it gets ready more quickly and thats about it. From functionality perspective there should be no difference at all

Answer (score 1):

The two platforms on the right (Unity and Flutter) both are meta-platforms, they wrap the 3 native platforms on the left.

When you click the Flutter icon, it gives you instructions on how to use the CLI to add the necessary app(s). If you after that go back to the Firebase console, you will see those native apps.

Also see the documentation on [getting started with Flutter on Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios), including the video embedded in there called [Add Firebase to your Flutter app: The fast way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkFvQ0SaT1I).

Answer (score 0):

I think the most imp benefit of choosing Flutter among the option is that you don't need to explicitly create apps per platform. The `flutterfire_cli` will create it automatically for you and add the required configuration files.
Check the below screenshot:

[image]